# Replacing data c# MVC

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this problem
I have a array of objects,which object have properties like

```
Date {get;set;}
Value {get;set;}
ServerLocation {get;set;}
```

So I have an array for example -

```
testing = {a,b,c,}
```

which are objects of this class.
I have values from another double array where I store values.
I want to replace the array of objects values with this values from the array of doubles.
So I can do this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
 {
     data[i].Value = approximateData[i];
 }
```

where data is my array of objects and `approximateDate` is the array of doubles.
How can I do it more Object Oriented? I tried casting but it went wrong.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure what you meant by Object Oriented way. But I have got few feedback on this. Might help you -

1. The overall approach seems not right. If you are asking for proper OO way, then it is not usual to save parts of object in a separate array and then replace them. That feels like procedural approach like we had in C. When you have objects with you, why not save directly in the object.
2. Considering you are staying on the current approach of keeping values in separate array, if you are only assigning the `Value` property, then I would say, the loop is okay. But if you need more properties to assign then I would prefer extension methods or constructors with parameter.